# update multiple buttons of an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state which I need to update multiple buttons in a nested object and then using dispatch for redux to update the store but still didn't find a good solution for it:

I have the following interface which I would like to send the data following its structure:

```
interface Object {
        name: string;
        buttons: {
          button1: number;
          button2: number;
          button3: number;
          button4: number;
      };
}
```

So I want to avoid the solution where my state of updating the state would be like this:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [button1, setButton1] = useState(0);
  const [button1, setButton1] = useState(0);
  const [button1, setButton1] = useState(0);
  const [button1, setButton1] = useState(0);
```

And I want to submit my form where I would have a state like this one:

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
      name: "";
      buttons: {
        button1: 0;
        button2: 0;
        button3: 0;
        button4: 0;
  };
})

function submit() {
  dispatch( {
      name: "";
      buttons: {
        button1: 3;
        button2: 6;
        button3: 8;
        button4: 4;
```

})
}

so when I try to increment and decrement my buttons I usually do like this which I want to avoid:

```
// increment
 onClick={() => setButton1(button1 + 1)}

// decrement
 onClick={() => setButton1(button1 - 1)}
```

So is there a better solution for it?

Comment: This is where `useReducer ` can help. You can do simply just keeps track from which button it its clicked. And update only that button

Answer (score 1):

Full Example

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0])

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const key = event.target.name

    // Copy state
    const newButtons = [...buttons]
    // Update state
    newButtons[key] += 1
    // Submit state
    setButtons(newButtons)
    console.log(buttons)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button name="1" onClick={handleClick}>1 Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PS. If you wanna full clone nested object, you need create cloneObject func or use Immer library, clone(cloneDeep) func from lodash

Full Example with name property

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import cloneDeep from "lodash.clone"

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    buttons: [0, 0, 0, 0]
  })

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const key = event.target.name

    // Copy state
    const newState = cloneDeep(state)
    // Update state
    newState.buttons[key] += 1
    // Submit state
    setState(newState)
    console.log(state)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button name="1" onClick={handleClick}>1 Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: didn't got your way, could you explain more ?

Comment: Updated message and add two examples with the library and without. If you don't want to use a clone library you may create your own but I think it's not recommended.